# Cannot Inject Dependency Into Derived Class

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs, reflect-metadata

I have a relatively simple setup with three classes. I am using `inversify` for dependency injection. But when injecting the class `MessageBroker` into the derived class `Repository` the `MessageBroker` is undefined:

```js
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { injectable, inject, Container, unmanaged } from 'inversify';

const container = new Container();

const registerProviders = (...providers: any[]) =>
  providers.forEach(provider => container.bind(provider.name).to(provider));

const getProvider = (provider): any => container.get(provider.name);

@injectable()
export class MessageBroker {
  start = () => console.log('init message broker');
}

@injectable()
export abstract class Repository {
  @inject(MessageBroker.name) private mb: MessageBroker;

  constructor(@unmanaged() protected readonly user: any) {}

  // this.mb is undefined
  initialize = () => this.mb.start();
}

@injectable()
export class UserRepository extends Repository {
  constructor() {
    super({ user: 'some object' });
    this.initialize();
  }
}

registerProviders(UserRepository, Repository, MessageBroker);

const repo: UserRepository = getProvider(UserRepository);
```

You can try it yourself. I've created a small GitHub repository: https://github.com/flolude/stackoverflow-inversify-injected-service-undefined

When running the script, I get this error:

```
/project/index.ts:22
  initialize = () => this.mb.start();
                             ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
    at UserRepository.Repository.initialize (/project/index.ts:22:30)
    at new UserRepository (/project/index.ts:29:10)
    at _createInstance (/project/node_modules/inversify/lib/resolution/instantiation.js:21:12)
    at Object.resolveInstance (/project/node_modules/inversify/lib/resolution/instantiation.js:41:18)
    at /project/node_modules/inversify/lib/resolution/resolver.js:72:42
    at Object.resolve (/project/node_modules/inversify/lib/resolution/resolver.js:96:12)
    at /project/node_modules/inversify/lib/container/container.js:319:37
    at Container._get (/project/node_modules/inversify/lib/container/container.js:310:44)
    at Container.get (/project/node_modules/inversify/lib/container/container.js:230:21)
    at getProvider (/project/index.ts:9:50)
```

P.S. I get pretty much the same error when compiling the code to Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Your MessageBroker has only been set in memory but has never been instantiated, which is how it is getting the undefined error. In your constructor you will need to set

`this.mb = new MessageBroker();`

Another way you can do this without the above line is to add a empty parameter signatured constructor into the MessageBroker class.

Comment: Doesn't it defeat the whole purpose of dependency injection? Would be cool if you'd show an example for your second method :)

Comment: DI still requires something that exists.
`export class MessageBroker {
  constructor() {}
  start = () => console.log('init message broker');
}`

Comment: Another example, this is an Angular 4 Example, but still uses Typescript nonetheless:

`@Injectable()
export class ReferenceNumberTableService {
  constructor(private globals: GlobalService, private http: Http) { } //These GlobalService is also an Injectable Service. and Http is an @angular/core import.
  //Other methods here.
  }
`
Used here in the component file:
`constructor(readonly referenceNumberTableService: ReferenceNumberTableService) {
}
`

Comment: The empty constructor doesn't work. Calling `this.mb = new MessageBroker();` does work. But I don't get why I need to create a new instance. I usually don't have to do this with DI

Comment: `@inject(MessageBroker.name) private mb: MessageBroker;` isn't actually inject it the way you need it to. If you wanted to inject it without a new instance of Message Broker you would have to put the MessageBroker in your Repository constructor by adding: private mb: MessageBroker and deleting the above mentioned line. You can see how I did that in my  example where ReferenceTableService is an Injectable Service and I stuck it in the component's constructor. That would also work. Without you doing that you  need to make a new instance. The constructor setup would create a new one for you.

Comment: Sorry I been responding to this at work so my brain has been focusing on that.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But then I get an error telling me that I need to provide an argument in the `super()` of the `UserRepository`... So I guess I have to inject the `MessageBroker` into the `UserRepository` and pass it down through the `super()` ?